# FirebaseFirestore not executing the given query

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

[image]I am try to import a single field value from a document.The problem here is code is not printing giving the error.I have check the code from firestore documentation too.

I tried using OnSuccessListener too,yet no result.

```
private FirebaseFirestore db,db1;
Map<String,Object > number=new HashMap<>();


db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();

   DocumentReference docRef = db.collection("goals").document(email);
    docRef.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {

        @Override
          public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DocumentSnapshot> task) {
              String TAG="lol";
              System.out.println("IT CAME Here") ;
              if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                  DocumentSnapshot document = task.getResult();
                  if (document.exists()) {
                      Log.d(TAG, "DocumentSnapshot data: " + document.getData());
                       number=document.getData();
                       name = document.getString("number");
                  } else {
                      Log.d(TAG, "No such document");
                  }
              } else {
                  System.out.println("get failed with ");
                  Log.d(TAG, "get failed with ", task.getException());
              }
          }
      });
```

Not even the print statements in the else loops are being printed.It seems like its skipping that block of code

Comment: Is your `onComplete()` even triggered?

Comment: no its not getting triggered

Comment: Are sure yu have internet connection? Does `task.getException()` print something?

Comment: I have a good internet connection .No, task.exception doesn't print anything.

Comment: please help me with this query

Comment: Are you sure you have implemented Firestore correctly?